# Calculate mean value of an image dataset

Tags: python, statistics, deep-learning

In deep learning experiments,there is a consensus that mean subtraction from the data set could improve the accuracy.For example,the mean value of ImageNet is [104.0 117.0 124.0],so before feeding the network,the mean value will be subtracted from the image. My question is

- How the mean value is calculated?
- Should I calculate the mean value on training and testing data set separately?

Comment: _"It will be appreciated if anyone could provide the python code to answer my questions."_ We are not a code provisioning service. Please read on [what topics that you can ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thank you for your comment,I have modified my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean value of the dataset is the mean value of the pixels of all the images across all the colour channels (e.g. RBG). Grey scale images will have just one mean value and colour images like ImageNet will have 3 mean values.

Usually mean is calculated on the training set and the same mean is used to normalize both training and test images.

Comment: S Kirubackaran,Thank you for your answer,I just want to know is there any tools to calculate mean value of a data set or I just have to do it all myself.

Comment: I'm afraid you have to do it yourself. This shouldn't be a big deal. You just have to subtract the mean values from the corresponding color channel